# Set custom System.StatusCode when using SObject addError method in Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, validation

I want to prevent the deletion of certain records. The implementation (excerpt of my domain method) for that is pretty straight-forward:

```java
public static void preventDeletionForBilledLineItems(List<ContractLineItem> oldRecords) {
    for (ContractLineItem cli : oldRecords) {
        // ** redacted for brevity ** //
        if (decorator.isBilled()) {
            cli.addError(System.Label.Cannot_Delete_Billed_Contract_Line_Item);
        }
    }
}
```

This works flawlessly in triggers and effectively prevents the user (and any apex code) from deleting the record.

However, the error code is very generic. I cannot set the *type* of error that occured. Salesforce always sets the `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION`. Technically, this is not even correct: I did not validate a certain field, I validated the record.

In order to test the code, this is an example assert one would have to write (the latter mainly to catch unhandled exceptions that could also cause the DML to fail):

```java
System.assertEquals(false, dr.isSuccess(), 'deleted successful');
System.assertEquals(System.StatusCode.FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, dr.getErrors()[0].getStatusCode(), 'status code');
```

It is basically impossible to distinguish different types of errors that may occur this way in my tests (asserting on error messages is not practical with validation rules due to the volatility of UI messages)

It would be much more intuitive and readable, if we could set a more appropriate status code such as the `DELETE_FAILED` or `DELETE_NOT_ALLOWED` when we assign an error in the trigger.

```java
System.assertEquals(false, dr.isSuccess(), 'deleted successful');
System.assertEquals(System.StatusCode.DELETE_FAILED, dr.getErrors()[0].getStatusCode(), 'status code');
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: What is the context for calling preventDeletionForBilledLineItems? Is this from a trigger?

Comment: I clarified in the original question, thx. Of course, it's a trigger context.

Answer (score 1):

Each `StatusCode` value has a specific meaning. `DELETE_FAILED` specifically means that a cascading deletion error occurred. Code that relies on these `StatusCode` values being deterministic would break if we could assign any arbitrary `StatusCode` to any error, since they could be whatever we think they should be. If Apex or a Validation Rule blocks a DML operation, we get the specific error `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION`; this is a vital hint that tells us where we should look if we want to find out what caused the error. If we could override this, it would be much harder to tell where the error came from.

Comment: thx for your reply - I tried to address the misunderstandings and tried to clarify my intention in the question. I would prefer to be very specific and descriptive with my error messages, that's all :).

Comment: Error messages are something quite different to status codes. I agree with @sfdcfox - stick with the standard behaviour.

Comment: Mh, I understand the consideration, that the status code should tell me of the origin, not the intention of the error.